# Context manager within a context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have a context manager, `S3TempFile`, that takes a local file, uploads it to s3, lets you make use of the s3 file, and on exit deletes the file from s3.

I want to create another, `S3TempRecordsFile`, which takes a list of records, does some processing on them, outputs to a local file, uploads it to s3, lets you make use of the s3 file, and on exit deletes the file from s3 and on local disk.

As you can see, the second does something extra on top of what  `S3TempFile` does. I'd like to reuse the `S3TempFile` code in `S3TempRecordsFile`. How would I do this? I can't use the `with` statement in `S3TempRecordsFile` to create a `S3TempFile` instance, as we only want to exit that one when we exit the `S3TempRecordsFile` context.

Comment: Sup dawg, I heard you like context managers.

Comment: More seriously, could you just make `S3TempRecordsFile` inherit from `S3TempFile` and call its inherited `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to re-use its functionality?